# Chart.JS tooltip callbacks label and title (v3.5)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, chart.js, chart.jsv3

(**Please note:** There are lots of answers for v2, this is for v3)

I'm trying to setup tooltips `label` and `title` for a doughnut chart.

Code:

```
        //Create the donut chart
    donut = new Chart('questions_positivity_donut', {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: { 
            labels: ["Positive", "Other"],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Sentiment',
                data: [user_context.state.avg_joy, (1-user_context.state.avg_joy)],
                backgroundColor: ['#a9a9a9','#f2f2f2']
            }]
        },
        options: {
            cutout: "70%",
            plugins: {
                legend: {
                    display: false
                },
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                responsive: true,
                tooltip: {
                    callbacks: {
                        label: function(context) {

                            let label = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {style: 'percent', minimumFractionDigits: 0, maximumFractionDigits: 0}).format(context.formattedValue);
                            return label;
                        },
                        title: function(context) {

                            let title = context.parsed.x;
                            return title;
                        } 
                    },
                    displayColors: false
                }                   
            }
        }
    });
```

The `label` now works, and displays the value of the data, but the `title` is returning blank, instead of returning the label of the data ("Positive" or "Other").

How can I return the correct title in the `tooltip.callback`?

Example: "Positive 35%" and "Other 65%"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you log the context you could see its an array containing objects, with the default interaction mode you are using it only contains a single item so you can select that one and then access the `label` attribute on it like so:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        callbacks: {
          label: function(context) {

            let label = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
              style: 'percent',
              minimumFractionDigits: 0,
              maximumFractionDigits: 0
            }).format(context.formattedValue);
            return label;
          },
          title: function(context) {
            let title = context[0].label;
            return title;
          }
        },
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I tried and I got this error: `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`.

Comment: Seems to work just fine so if it doesnt work please share a reproducable sample

Comment: Sorry, I meant the console.log. Yes - this is perfect! Accepted! Thanks

Comment: how did you log this? I'm trying and still failing

Comment: @Izzi Sorry for the late reaction but I just putted it like this: `console.log(context)`